# How to avoid child updates inside Fluent NHibernate many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a simple many-to-many relationship using Fluent NHibernate and it is working pretty fine.

Here is my first class mapping:

```
    public LobMapping()
    {
        ...
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Commodities)
            .Table("PPBSYS.LOB_COMMODITY")
            .ParentKeyColumn("LOB_ID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("COMMODITY_ID")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .LazyLoad();
        ...
    }
```

Here is my second class mapping:

```
    public CommodityMapping()
    {
        ...
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Lobs)
            .Table("PPBSYS.LOB_COMMODITY")
            .ParentKeyColumn("COMMODITY_ID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("LOB_ID")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All()
            .LazyLoad();
        ...
    }
```

And finally, my Lob object has a list of commodities:

```
public class Lob
{
    ...
    public virtual IEnumerable<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

However I am not happy with the fact that I must reference the entire commodity inside the Lob class. I really would like to do:

```
var lob = new Lob();
lob.Commodities = new [] { new Commodity { CommodityId = 1 }}; 
repository.SaveLob(lob);
```

But if I run the code above, NHibernate will try to update the Commodity table setting the columns to null for the commodity with ID = 1.

So actually I must get the entire object, before saving the Lob:

```
var lob = new Lob();
lob.Commodities = new [] { repostitory.GetCommodit(1) };
repository.SaveLob(lob);
```

And I *know* that the commodity exists, because the user just have selected them.

It is possible to accomplish my task?

Comment: You can't give it a full entity with just ID , ofcourse it will try to delete everything in it, You can try (don't know if it will work) : Map the keyColumn of the Commodity with the same name you set in the manytomany "COMMODITY_ID", and try to set that column only and save, that worked for me in a simple HasMany

Comment: In fact the primary key of Commodity is CommodityId (same as the N-N relationship).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your repository is calling `session.Get<T>(id)` under the covers.  There is also `session.Load<T>(id)`.

```
lob.Commodities = new [] { session.Load<Commodity>(1) };
```

From the [NHibernate documentation on `Load()`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading)...

> If the class is mapped with a proxy, Load() returns an object that is an uninitialized proxy and does not actually hit the database until you invoke a method of the object. This behaviour is very useful if you wish to create an association to an object without actually loading it from the database.

Comment: This is really promising. Let me check this.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Just be aware that the Entity must be a available for Lazy Loading (virtual members and mapping).

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer sounds promising, let me know if in Save the proxy won't hit the database to fill all the properties of the entity.

Another answer would be a little forcefully on Nhibernate, i tested it and it's working,
working code :

```
public class Com
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Lob> Lobs { get; set; }
}

public class Lob
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Com> Coms { get; set; }
}

class LobMap : ClassMap<Lob>
{
    public LobMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Coms)
        .Table("LOB_COM")
        .ParentKeyColumn("LOB_ID")
        .ChildKeyColumn("COM_ID")
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
        .LazyLoad();
    }
}

class ComMap : ClassMap<Com>
{
    public ComMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Lobs)
        .Table("LOB_COM")
        .ParentKeyColumn("COM_ID")
        .ChildKeyColumn("LOB_ID")
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.All()
        .LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Now - I set a dummy entity to mimic the connection table and map it :

```
public class ComLobConnection
{
    public virtual Guid ComID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid LobID { get; set; }
}

public class ComLobConnectionMap : ClassMap<ComLobConnection>
{
    public ComLobConnectionMap()
    {
        Table("LOB_COM");

        Id();

        Map(x => x.ComID,"COM_ID");
        Map(x => x.LobID,"LOB_ID");
    }
}
```

Notice that i'm mapping to exact same fields and Table as the ManyToMany, with no ID set up (that's the empty Id() call)

Now all that's left is to save a ComLobConnection and it will be added to the Com.Lobs and Lob.Coms

Saved some test Com,Lob

```
        var testCom = new Com() { Name = "TestCom" };
        var testLob = new Lob() { Name = "TestLob" };
        session.SaveOrUpdate(testCom);
        session.SaveOrUpdate(testLob);
```

after save - took their ID's and saved a connection to test

```
        var testConnection = new ComLobConnection()
        {
            ComID = Guid.Parse("D3559F53-8871-45E9-901D-A22800806567"),
            LobID = Guid.Parse("D372D430-2E61-44F2-BA89-A228008065F1")
        };
        session.SaveOrUpdate(testConnection);
```

This forced a new record in the manytomany table, and worked when getting both Lob and Com after.

I'm not recommending this :), It just interested me if it can be done, and it can.
This way you will not hit the DB for loading Coms or Lobs that you know exist to save their connection.

Hopefully Load() will not hit the DB for that too :)

Edit : can be done with any kind of ID

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will try Daniel's answer and see if the database does not complain.